# Android: Store data that can be accessed by multiple applications

Tags: android

I have scenario where there are 4 (or more) applications, the first one which runs on a device (it can be any one of the 4 applications) will generate a Unique ID and store it on some where, and all other applications which runs afterwards requires to read Unique ID that was generated by the first running application.

I want to exclude `External Storage` option as some user may easily change the stored value.

I also considered `Shared Preferences`, but it seems using `Shared Preferences` we can implement multiple applications to read the data generated by a single application, but all applications cannot write this shared data.

Comment: Use a remote server and connect through an API.

Comment: @AnirudhSharma my requirement is to identify the client device where my applications installed. we cannot use this option for the this scenario.

Comment: You can use content provider. Content Provider's purpose in android is to share data across multiple applications(Processes).

Comment: @muditsen1234, I have not created `Content Providers` before, I will try. But I think 'Content Provider' pattern requires one application to register as `Provider` and all other applications requires to be on receiving end. In my scenario, any one of the 4 application can be the `Provider` and all other applications should be in receiving end. Still is it achievable using `Content Provider`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also have the Sqlite DB option and share a ContentProvider for the other applications to be able to access or modify the data. The advantage is that this data will be stored locally, the disadvantage will be that if you want a security for your data you will have to encrypt your data or choose the Remote Server option.

Comment: In the above given scenario, if I have to use `Content Provider` pattern, Any one of the 4 applications can be the `Provider` depends on the which application runs first. Since the provider cannot not be determined at development (Compile) time. I think the same provider name cannot be used for multiple applications

Comment: You can make one application to store the ContentProvider and the Sqlite DB and give write/read rights to the other applications. Please see here more information on this topic: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html